# How to change language in Dead Space 3?

Tags: dead-space-3

How do I change Dead Space 3 interface language to English?

Comment: Are you using Steam?

Comment: Some multi-language games tend to default to the OS language for interface language. So, if, for example, you're playing the game on the PS3, try changing your system language in the console settings then booting the game.

Comment: Dead Space 3 is not on Steam.

Comment: List platform are you using - PC/PS3/XBOX

Answer (score 1):

If you Using Origin you can do this:

1. On the Origin Client go to Origin>Application Settings>General>Interface>Origin Client Language.
2. Change the value to whatever language you want.
3. Go to Origin Games folder in program files and rename "Dead Space 3" folder to "Dead Space 3BAK" (really shouldn't matter what u rename it to)
4. Go back to Origin client (I didn't have to close it before renaming the folder) and notice the game now says "Download" instead of "Play"
5. Hit Download on Dead Space 3 game (it will create a new "Dead Space 3" folder)
6. Go to the game download dialogue and click on the Pause icon to stop the download
7. Go back to the Origin Games folder and Move/Replace everything from your "Dead Space 3BAK" into the new "Dead Space 3" folder. (Don't copy-paste, that will take longer and hog more HDD space).
8. Go back to the Origin download dialogue window and click on the download icon button. For me it took seconds to go from 0% to 100%. (I am not sure but I think it only downloaded one new file: "GDFBinary_en_US.dll"
9. Play and enjoy game in English!!

Answer (score 1):

Create a system environment variable `EAGameLocale` with value `en_US`.

I've found this recommendation [here](https://answers.ea.com/t5/Dead-Space-Games/Dead-Space-3-Language-change/m-p/581756#M3371). Did it before installing the game. I still had no option to choose English language for installation. But the game now in English language.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Region and Language" in "Control Panel", change the country to US, and it should work